# Check if a number is present in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe with a column 'Letter' which is filled with letter going from A to Z. I would like to check if Letter H is in the column, and if yes how many times is it present.

Can Someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. After taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you will even have some rewards), please, see how to produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, edit the question providing a sample of your data, what you have tried and/or stucked, and the *desired output*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to get the occurrence of the letter `H` in column `Letter`

```
freq = (df['Letter'].values == "H").sum()
```

It will return the number of occurrence if not present will return 0

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. `found` is the number of occurrences of `H`. Will be `0` if none.

```
found = df[df['Letter'].str.contains('H')]
```